# Saving Excel file as CSV while excluding header in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have written  the following code:

```
Sub create_talpo_kiint_csv()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim PathName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").range("B2", range("B2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Select
    FileName = "test.csv"
    PathName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    ws.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=PathName & "\" & FileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

The goal is to save the excel file as csv while excluding the header. However, the code above is not working. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What does your code do versus what did you expect or what errors did you get and where?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ws.Copy` copies the entire worksheet regardles your selection. So I recommend to delete the header after the copy.

```
ws.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).Delete Shift:=xlUp  ' delete first row
```

Make sure you set `ws` just to the worksheet then

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")
```